# Spring Hadoop Java config

Tags: spring-data-hadoop

What is the current state of JavaConfig support? As I see it's possible to set up Hadoop configuration this way: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-config.html#using-the-spring-for-apache-hadoop-javaconfig. But what about jobs, job runners, Hive and HBase configuration? Is it already supported in some way? Is it planned for some future release?
And finally, for now, what is the best practice for Hadoop configuration using Spring Hadoop?

Comment: Did you get an answer for your question?